# Blue tint on right half of tv screen

Tags: tv, 4k-resolution

I bought a used display tv from Walmart. It's a philips model 55pfl5602 f7, with 4k ultra HD. I've tried adjusting every setting on the tv, but the right side is always bluer. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I can guess why it was being sold as a used display.  Simplest fix: return it and make it someone else's problem.  If it's half the display, it isn't something that's a simple, cheap fix, or that can be adjusted.

Comment: That was my ultimate guess. I did return it, only then was I told by my coworkers (I work at the Walmart I got it from), that apparently there was a massive blackout and a ton of the TV's were damaged. So much for friends, right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-setting the TV to it's factory defaults?

http://philips-tvconsumercare.kxondemand.com/portal/en/Faq/All/1462